# Programatic UIButton erratic behaviour

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

So I'm creating a UIButton programmatically based on whether a value on one of my objects is > 0. However when I edit that value and reload the table it wont remove the button. The value is definitely > 0 and not nil as its being displayed in a label.
Ive tried adding the button to every cell and then setting its hidden property, which is giving me the same behavior as the code below. If I stop the app and re-run the app it displays how it should.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    CGRect newIconRect = CGRectMake(280, 5, 33, 33);
    UIButton *warningButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:newIconRect];
    warningButton.tag = 66;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:warningButton];
}

    UIButton *warningButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:66];
    [warningButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exclamation.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [warningButton addTarget:self action:@selector(warningButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if (ueo.daysLeft >= 0)
    {
    daysLeftLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i recurringDays to go", ueo.daysLeft];

    warningButton.hidden = YES;

    }
    else
    {
    daysLeftLabel.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%i recurringDays have passed", ueo.daysLeft];
    warningButton.hidden = NO;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating duplicate buttons in the cell if you are doing it as shown in the question. So you will not be able to remove the buttons since you might have already lost the reference to button objects. For reach reload or table view scroll, the above code will create new buttons and add on top of the cell.

You can either customize the `UITableViewCell` and add this button in the `init` method of that cell class. After that you can show/hide using

```
cell.button.hidden = YES;//or NO
```

An easy but not recommended approach is to do this part in `if (cell == nil)`,

For eg:-

```
if (cell == nil) {
   //create cell here
   cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

   CGRect newIconRect = CGRectMake(280, 5, 33, 33);
   UIButton *warningButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:newIconRect];
   warningButton.tag = 100;   
   [cell.contentView addSubview:warningButton];    
}

UIButton *warningButton = (UIButton *)[cell.contenView viewWithTag:100];
NSLog(@"warningButton = %@", warningButton);
[warningButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"exclamation.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[warningButton addTarget:self action:@selector(warningButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

if (ueo.daysLeft >= 0) {
  warningButton.hidden = YES;
} else {
  warningButton.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what you say makes sense, unfortunately it doesn't seem to be creating the button at all. I'm not sure what more I can tell you to help?

Comment: @justMike, Can you please post the actual cellForRowAtIndexPath method code. I am sure there are some code to create a cell there. You need to add it below there.

Comment: I updated the code, sorry about the formatting my mouse is acting up.

Comment: @justMike, Code looks fine. Are you sure the hidden property is set to NO, when you want to display?

Comment: Yup, Ive even tried setting all instances of the button to NO

Comment: @justMike, check if it is pointing to valid memory by doing NSLog as `NSLog(@"warningButton = %@", warningButton);`

Comment: If you add a breakpoint, can you see that your pointer to warningButton is valid? Have you verified that ueo.daysLeft is what you're expecting?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be instantiating an instance of warningButton. My ueo.daysLeft property is definitely working though. Its appear in the label and in my showing up in my debug.

Comment: @justMike, Add a break point in `if (cell == nil) {` and check if it is executing that button initialization part.

Comment: Its not breaking in the if (cell == nil) { statement at all

Comment: @justMike, I wonder how your cell is getting created then? Are you sure your code looks exactly as shown in question? Add a break point and check if your cell is pointing to valid memory address in that line. At least in the beginning while creating table view, it should call this.

Comment: Im putting a breakpoint on the 'cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:...' but its not breaking lol. Ive got a couple of other things being loaded but just labels etc, nothing fancy. If I load it in the main 'cellForRow' method it shows up but seems to have no common behavior to it. Thanks for trying, I need some sleep. Ill have a look again in the morning.

Comment: @justMike, Yup, try again later and update. Mostly you are missing something obvious.

Comment: It is, and honestly I cant tell you what the problem was. I cleaned up my if statements and simplified some code which got it working. I was going to just delete this posted but I wanted to give you some credit for your effort and hopefully your answer might help someone else.

Comment: @justMike, Thanks. That's what I said. Something obvious which we normally tend to miss cause these troubles.. Anyways good to know that it got solved.